# Cannot open 'PDF portfolio'

Tags: pdf, evince, adobe-acrobat

How can I open a pdf portfolio (pdf file which contains multiple pdfs) that was made with Adobe on Mac or PC?

I've tried FoxIt, Evince, and qpdfview but none of them work.

I get a message saying "For the best experience, open this PDF portfolio in Acrobat X or Adobe Reader X, or later." Unfortunately this is not possible since Adobe does not seem to support these on Ubuntu any more.

Comment: It's difficult to assess the available options without access to a similar file. If you could provide a link to a PDF Portfolio it might result in further attention to the question.

Answer (score 12):

My solution is based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/743608/123317) which suggests a few different PDF applications:

> [image]

I found that not all these programs actually work for this. In my case `pdftk` did not work and `okular` did. One down side with Okular is that you have to export the PDFs contained in a portfolio into individual files:

1. Open with Okular

[image]

2. Click first item then `ctrl+a` to select all

[image]

3. You'll be prompted to select a file name and location. You can just keep hitting enter.

It's not as good an experience as using Adobe but it gets the job done.

Comment: For me pdftk and pdfdetach worked, while evince and okular failed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Evince with version 3.18.2 is reported to work, available in Xenial.

Answer (score 4):

Try  **evince**,  the GNOME document viewer

Hit F9 to make the sidebar on the left visible, then at the top of the Sidebar there is the "Thumbnails" menu. Click it.

---

Then you'll see this:

[image]

---

- I guess, by default "Thumbnails" is selected.

[image: Menu]
Then you can change to "Attachments".

---

This will make the Embedded PDFs visible (see below). **You can click on any red PDF icons in the sidebar individually. It will open in a new pdf Window.** 
You can also multi-select (click topmost icon, hold shift, click lowermost icon)  the icons and then save them all at once, into individual files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although Adobe has discontinued support for Adobe Reader, you can still download a version 9.5.5 from their website, and install it manually:

```
wget http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
sudo dpkg -i AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

You should be able to view PDF Portfolio files with this version.

Comment: capital P causes wget to fail

Comment: Followed this and got an error during install. Now I have Adobe installed but it crashes every time I open it. Ubuntu 16.04 - 64 bit.

Comment: @PK-Killer You don't need the P option, I will remove it from my answer.

Comment: it works if you change it to a small p

Answer (score -2):

Type "about:plugins" in the Chrome address bar, and then Disable 'PDF Viewer'. You will then be able to open PDF Portfolio documents as well. Check it out.

Comment: Well, what operating system are you using, and what app? They would also work if you re-enable Chrome's special security features around risky pdfs, and download the file for local viewing.